# Eliminar todos los valores de un array menos el ultimo

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber si se pueden borrar todos los elementos de un array menos el ultimo valor, por ejemplo:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

que al borrar quede:

```
var arr =[5]
```

Conozco sobre `pop()`, `shift()`, etc. pero no he logrado hacerlo.

Answer (score 7):

Reemplaza "last_arr" por el último valor del "arr"

```
var last_arr = [arr[arr.length-1]];
```

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y ponelo en la respuesta. De paso, lee [answer] para una proxima.

Comment: Bienvenido y gracias por demostrar como hacer simple algo que es simple... :)

Comment: Gracias por el consejo!!

Answer (score 2):

Podrias intentar con lo siguiente.

Lo que se hace es contar cuantos son y hacer la eliminación excepto el ultimo por eso el -1

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.splice(0, arr.length - 1);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando `pop()`:

```
const ultimo = [arr.pop()];
```

Si la cantidad de elementos a eliminar o la posicion es dinámica, también puedes utilizar `splice()` o `slice()`, este último a diferencia de `splice()`, retorna una copia, de manera que el original queda intacto:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

const arr2 = arr.slice(-1,arr.lenght);

console.log(arr);    
console.log(arr2);
```

En ambos puedes comenzar por el final, por eso el -1 como primer argumento.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes es hacer un [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice#Par%C3%A1metros) para cortar tu arreglo, la diferencia es que envia el resultado de lo cortado(no modifica el arreglo) caso contrario con `shift()` y el `pop()`:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
const nuevo = arr.slice(-1)
console.log(nuevo);
const array_restante =  arr.slice(0 , -1)
console.log(array_restante);
```

Puedes Observar que el segundo parametro tiene un -1, significa que se desplazara -1 de la longitud del arreglo, como lo dice la documentacion:

> Indica un desplazamiento desde el final de
>   la secuencia. slice(2,-1) extrae desde el tercer hasta el penúltimo
>   elemento en la secuencia.

---

***Adicional***

El [Array.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/pop), Elimina el ultimo elemento del arreglo

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log("antes", arr);
arr.pop()
console.log("ahora", arr);
```

El [Array.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/shift) Elimina la primera posición del arreglo

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log("antes", arr);
arr.shift()
console.log("ahora", arr);
```

Si quieres usar shift(), puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
const longitud = a.length;
for (let i =0; i< longitud -1   ; i++){
  a.shift()
}
console.log(a)
```